# Animals walking backward?

Tags: human-biology

Have you ever noticed that we humans can walk forward and backward but animals don't walk backwards?I guess this is true with most of the animals.What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Most animals can walk backwards if they really want to, or if you make them. The reason they, and we, tend not to walk backwards most of the time is that most animals and people don't have eyes in the back of their heads, and would risk running into things or falling off cliffs. You might try walking backwards all day and see what is the result, but please do not hold me liable if you end up in hospital.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a false premise.

Comment: Sorry but I never noticed them do so.Anyways thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is incorrect other animals can [and do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybbv6O73usI) walk backwards. Like humans, other animals do most of their walking forward both for biomechanical reasons and for the obvious reason that it is easier to see where you are going when walking forward.